# Image uploader with crop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, image-uploading

I want to upload multiple images in asp.net web application but I need although to crop image for prefixed size before upload.

Is there any available Java script, JQuery ,...  control for uploading image with cropping ability by fixed size crop square ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Cropper](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/).

With the Cropper.js, you can select a specific area of an image, and then upload the coordinates data to server-side to crop the image, or crop the image on browser-side directly.